# Dell Inspiron 15 3521 Webcam not working

Tags: windows-8, drivers, webcam, dell-inspiron

I have windows 8 installed on dell Inspiron 15 3521.
I did not find any drivers for windows 8 webcam.
Do I need some drivers for it or not?
I have windows 8 pro 9200 build.

Comment: Check device manager if the driver is already installed. Also what you can try, a lot of times drivers from Vista/7 suit Windows 8 just as good

Comment: Have you tried the drivers you could find?  Some Windows 7 drivers can work on Windows 8.  If those don't work then your likely going to need different hardware, hardware that supports Windows 8, if you want to use a webcam.

Answer (score 1):

Dell offer a diagnostic tool which will automatically scan your machine and either fix or recommend fixes etc

Follow this link to the [Dell PC Diagnostics](http://www.dell.com/support/Diagnostics/uk/en/ukdhs1) page and see if this detects and fixes the issue.

Answer (score -2):

Please Check device manager if the driver is already installed. Also what you can try, a lot of times drivers from Vista/7 suit Windows 10 just as good

Better windows 10 new 2016 --- Dell Inspiron 15 3542.

windows 10 upgrade assistant :https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/

Comment: This is just a copy of someone else's comment.

Comment: What does Windows 10 have to do with the author's question?